# php regex: finding custom tag

Tags: php, regex

I want to find content in "{foreach $data as $k => $v} ... {/foreach}" tags. But "$data","$k" and "$v" variables are not constant names. They could change. Also, I want to choose their names. For example: data: $data, key: $k, value: $v.

The following sample template

```
  <div id="Container">
        <span>Lorem Ipsum</span>
        <div>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
        {foreach $data as $k => $v}
            <div>another element</div>
            <span>another element</span>
            <p>another element</p>
            Lorem Ipsum
        {/foreach}  
        <div class="anotherElement">Lorem Ipsum</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: what is your question bhai ?

Comment: How do I do it with php regex?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/dK9gD3/1  something like this?

Comment: Yes man, thats true! but something is missing. I want to select content between {foreach ...} CONTENT {/foreach} tags

Comment: Ah, so... this should work: https://regex101.com/r/dK9gD3/3 However, this doesn't work if you have nested for each loops - some regex guru will solve it....

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/dK9gD3/5

Comment: thank you nevermind. This is enough for me!

Answer (score 1):

```
/{foreach \$[a-zA-Z_]+[[a-zA-Z0-9]* as \$[a-zA-Z_]+[a-zA-Z[0-9]* => \$[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*}([ |\n](.|\n)*){\/foreach}/
```

This should match regardless of the variable names.

The same regex with named variables;

```
/{foreach \$data as \$k => \$v}([ |\n](.|\n)*){\/foreach}/
```

Just replace the names as you see fit.